Can’t recover wallet
I have recently attempted to reactivate my phantom account and I used my 12 recovery phrase words but it opened what looked like to me a different account as none of my crypto was there for me to see? It had also bought in some crypto from my ledger which I am now unable to remove from the account. Can anyone help me please?
Thank you

There is two possibilities I can think of;
Possibility 1) you were scammed at some point and someone went into your account and took everything you had in it. To check, copy your public key on whatever network you THINK the tokens were on, and paste it in https://solscan.io/ (or ethscan or btC scan website depending on the chain it was supposed to be on.)
Possibility 2) is you have unregistered meme coins your account was holding and your account wont automatically show that sometimes. So, you go token list and then manually put in the token hash of the token you THINK you have and it'll look that token up and update the meta data and held amount in your wallet. Here's a youtube video; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-wpSjG6VHw
If it's not one of those issue than I don't know what wrong tbh. Only two things I can think of atm.
